# How do I use dynamically created html/javascript with ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am converting a web app from plain html/jquery to c#.net. I am trying to add this javascript/html code dynamically when I click a button on my webpage using asp.net. The js/html code is added to the page then disappears when it hits the server. Why is that? I'm new to asp.net. How do I make the code stay on the browser after clicking the Add button?

asp.net:

```
<asp:Button ID="addButton" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="javascript:Add()"/>
```

.js file:

```
  function Add() {
    $('tr').removeClass('select');
    $('tbody').append('<tr class="table-data-row" id="new-row"><td class="quantity"><input type="text" name="qty" class="input-qty" value=""/></td><td class="des"><input type="text" class="input-desc" name="desc"/></td><td><input type="text" class="input-price" name="price" value=""/></td><td class="capital"></td></tr>');
    $('#buttons').append('<button class="buttonSC" onclick="Save()">Save</button><button class="buttonSC" onclick="Cancel()">Cancel</button><p></p>');
    $('[name="qty"]').focus();
    $('.input-qty , .input-price').keyup(function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    });
  }
```

Comment: May I suggest using MVC, also JavaScript runs client-side and that code is a OnClientClick so it shouldn't hit the server. Let me know if the duplicate doesn't fix it.

Comment: Ok i found the solution, it took me 3 days to find/figure out. It was return false after the on  client click: "javascript:Add(); return false;"..... This will save me a lot of time, I am redoing some apps for work.